# Could not get unknown property 'resolutionStrategy' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, android

I was getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (25.3.1) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

A quick search on google showed me that I should include in my app/build.gradle:

```
 resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
        details.useVersion "25.3.1"
    }
}
```

Now I get a new error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'resolutionStrategy' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

here is my full app/build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'


    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.test.Test"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android" }
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()


    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':library')

    implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-core:4.0.8'
    implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-ui:4.0.8'
    implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-firebase-adapter:4.0.8'
    implementation 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-firebase-file-storage:4.0.8'

}

resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
        details.useVersion "25.3.1"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my library/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar')



}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using support dependencies, why are you creating a resolution strategy?

Comment: I dont know I have been getting this error: Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (25.3.1) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Comment: It basically means there is a dependency of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1` and if you are sure you don't have them in the build file, I'm guessing they are on your `:library` project. Do you have access to that code? Also, is targetting 27 absolutely necessary?

Comment: Do you mean the library/build.gradle?: Posted more code in my topic.

Comment: This line `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` is grabbing whatever jars you have on `src/main/libs`, and this one `implementation project(':library')` is expecting a folder named `library` in your main project folder. If you have jars, you will need the source code. If you have the library you need to update versions to API 27. If targeting 27 is not necessary it'll be just easier to target 25 for now.

Comment: You can also find out more about dependencies running `gradlew dependencyInsight`

Comment: Yes I have the jar https://github.com/vbartacek/aacdecoder-android in library/libs

Comment: You will need to recompile that targeting 27 or use 25 in your project

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org